Davinci Resolve 19.0 - record audio with usb microphone ALSA?
Running the freshly released Davinci Resolve Studio 19.0, with Ubuntu 24.04. My microphone works perfectly fine (Audacity runs perfectly.).
To record sound in Davinci Resolve, you must patch Audio inputs to tracks. Looks like this:

As you can see, I can patch 8 ALSA inputs to 4 tracks.
But No combination works. I tried all kinds of different combinations. This used to work in an older install of ubuntu and resolve.
Anyone know what I can do?

I too have this problem and read that you can replace pipewire with pulseaudio. I tried doing that and ended up corrupting my entire install of Ubuntu. Did you ever find a solution?
